# ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements"

Tags: ios, app-store, signature, entitlements, jira-mobile-connect

while uploading my application to the appstore I will get this error:

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, '#PREFIX#.#BUNDLE-IDENTIFIER#' for key 'application-identiffier' 'in Payload/#APPNAME#.app/Frameworks/JIRAMobileConnect.framework/JIRAMobileConnect' is not supported. This value should be a string with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier."

The #PREFIX# ist the correct one from the developer-portal. But in my Project the Prefix is never used.

I also tried to set the Build-Team to "NONE", but this doesn't helped.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are archiving via `xcodebuild -exportArchive`?

Comment: I have the same problem. framework don't support the app id. Need help too.

Comment: Also having the same issue, any information?

Comment: [ios - Re-signing an IPA that contains a Framework - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078983/re-signing-an-ipa-that-contains-a-framework)