# Re-signing an IPA that contains a Framework

Tags: ios, code-signing, ipa, codesign

I'm re-signing an iOS app (using iResign) in order to upload it to the App Store; and as part of this I'm changing the bundle ID.
**I only have the IPA (not the source code).**

The app contains a third party framework.

The resign appears to go fine; but when I upload using Application Loader, I get the following error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature 
contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. 
Specifically, value 'XXXXXXXXXX.COM.X.Y.Z.A' for key 'application-identifier' in 
'Payload/APPNAME.app/Frameworks/FRAMEWORKNAME.framework/FRAMEWORKNAME' is not supported. 
This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by
the bundle identifier."
```

(Obviously I've changed the values shown in CAPS)

I'm assuming that the problem is that the application-identifier in my entitlements.plist matches the Bundle identifier in my app, but does not match the Bundle identifier in the framework.

Just to rule it out, I set the same Bundle identifier on the framework and the app. This did allow me to upload to the app store; but failed with an error when I tried to install the app onto an iPad.

**Do I need to provide a separate entitlements file for the framework?
How can I get around this issue?**

**UPDATE**: Just to rule it out, I've tried using a wildcard provisioning profile and entitlements plist; but that gives the same error

Answer (score 5):

You must re-sign the frameworks too.

Just open your .ipa and find the frameworks used under

Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks

Try to sign them with command below

```
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Some Body (XXXXXXXXXX)" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/*
```

After that re-zip it.

Additionally, lots of people got good results with AirSign.

Comment: So you think that I should first sign the framework; and then separately sign the IPA?
I've given this an attempt, but it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: Also, I gave AirSign a shot, and had a similar error: "ERROR ITMS-90179: "Invalid Code Signing. The executable 'Payload/APPNAME.app/Frameworks/FRAMEWORKNAME.framework/FRAMEWORKNAME' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile.""

Comment: It is kinda different error. Unfortunately you may not submit/use this app without reaching to provisioning file and distribution cert from developer's account. If you can supply them please try solution below:(1) go in keychain and delete both certificates (dev & distribution)

(2) go to apple site and download distribution certificate only

(3) install distribution cert only!

(4) export p12 from private key

(5) go to apple and regenerate/download distribution provisioning profile.

Comment: Are you implying that AirSign does sign the frameworks? The reason I found this thread is because AirSign wasn't signing the framework apparently.

Comment: Any chance you found a solution to this? I've tried re-signing the Framework with the above codesign command and still get the exact same ITMS-90046 error. AirSign doesn't seem to exist anymore as well.

Answer (score 4):

#### Assuming you run all your regular actions like removing app signature then remove the old signature on frameworks and resign those frameworks without including the entitlements:

```
rm -r Payload/"$ipaExe"/Frameworks/*/_CodeSignature
codesign -f -s "$certificate" Payload/"$ipaExe"/Frameworks/*
```

#### Then sign your app itself:

```
codesign -f -s "$certificate" --entitlements $entitlementFile Payload/"$ipaExe"
```

Comment: Positive solution for me, thanks! resign frameworks without including the entitlements~

Answer (score 2):

It might be late, and you might already resolve your problem. But i hope my answer will help you and other people

I assume you already tried the command 'codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: ...." ' to resign or sign your app/frameworks/embedded libraries.
I usually use this command to resign my apps, but suddenly it's stopped working when I upgraded to iOS 10 and xcode 8.2. And I got the same problem as your with third party framework in my IPA file.

So I did some researches and found that XCode uses this command to sign app

```
/usr/bin/codesign '-vvv' '--force' '--sign' 'CFE5D63E6.......1CBCF2271B844' '--preserve-metadata=identifier,resource-rules' '--entitlements' '/var/folders/86/kd0n_tjd56v9thg5x5qwnx500000gp/T/XcodeDistPipeline.uqv/entitlementsWgXqGE' '/var/folders/86/kd0n_tjd56v9thg5x5qwnx500000gp/T/XcodeDistPipeline.uqv/Root/Payload/FrameworkTesting.app/Frameworks/......'
```

Notice that "CFE5D63E6.......1CBCF2271B844" identifier! It's the identifier of your certificate. So this is the solution to make the codesign work.

1. Use this command to list all identifiers of your certificates

   security find-identity -v -p codesigning

You will get a list look like this:

```
  1) 4BEC631CE717.......8C7CB311093548D4 "iPhone Developer: xxxx (xxxxx)"
  2) 4BEC631......BB678C7CB311093548D4 "iPhone Developer: xxxx (xxxx)"
  3) .......D45590A63E99A27D2977C573..... "iPhone Developer: xxxx (xxxx)"
  4) CF........6FDD78ECB161CBCF2271B844 "iPhone Distribution: xxxx (xxxx)"
  5) C4973F........352F620D2F49 "iPhone Developer: xxxx (xxxx)"
  6) 225........B6D70672E880479860ED6 "iPhone Distribution: xxxx (xxxx)"
     6 valid identities found
```

2. Use this command to sign your app/frameworks/libraries

   codesign -vvv --force --sign "[pick an identifier above]" Payload/yourAppp.app/Frameworks/yourFramework.framework

   codesign -vvv --force --sign "[pick an identifier above]" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/yourAppp.app

Hope this will help!

Comment: @venturidoo what error messages did you get? Please include them here, I will try to help :)